# When using int and float datatype, why does the output of "%d" appear different?

Tags: c, types, range, output, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    float b = 4;
    clrscr();
    printf("%d \n", a + b);
    printf("%f \n", a + b);
    printf("%d \n", a * b);
    printf("%f \n", a * b);
    printf("%d \n", b / a);
    printf("%f \n", b / a);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
-1293228905 
6.000000 
0 
8.000000 
0 
2.000000
```

Seems like its just taking the starting and ending range of the `int` datatype.

Comment: The type of `a+b` (or any operation combining a and b) will be `float`. If you want to print it as an int, you'll need to cast it to an int, e.g. `(int)(a+b)`.

Comment: All of the places you use `%d` there invoke undefined behaviour. The argument isn't compatible with `int`, so you shouldn't use `%d`.

Comment: Read the fine warnings. Think about them. What do they tell you? Why do they tell you that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior for all `printf` statements that use a `%d` conversion.  The reason is you pass a value of type `float` where `printf` will expect a value of type `int` to have been passed.

To evaluate the expression `a+b`, the compiler converts the `int` operand to type `float` and evaluates the addition using floating point computation. The type of the result is `float` too. The same applies to the other expressions.

Types `int` and `float` have a different representation and may be passed in different ways to vararg functions such as `printf`. Passing a `float` value where `printf` expects an `int` value results in undefined behavior: anything can happen, and it is vain to try and make sense of the surprising output.

If you mean to use `%d`, you must convert the value to type `int` explicitly with a cast:

```
    printf("%d \n", (int)(a + b));
```

Note that you can also use `%.0f` to output the `float` argument with no decimals, but the output will differ as `printf` will round the `float` value to the nearest integer, whereas `(int)(a + b)` will truncate the `float` value toward `0` if it can be represented as an `int`.

Note finally, that `float` values are implicitly promoted to `double` when passed to `printf` and other vararg functions. Using type `double` for all floating types is recommended unless you target very specific applications such as computer graphics or embedded systems.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    double b = 4;

    printf("a+b: %f  %d  %.0f\n", a + b, (int)(a + b), a + b);
    printf("a*b: %f  %d  %.0f\n", a * b, (int)(a * b), a * b);
    printf("a/b: %f  %d  %.0f\n", a / b, (int)(a / b), a / b);
    printf("b/a: %f  %d  %.0f\n", b / a, (int)(b / a), b / a);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a+b: 5.000000  5  5
a*b: 6.000000  6  6
a/b: 0.666667  0  1
b/a: 1.500000  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

In C The `%d` specifier is used to print an int value and `%f` using for print a float.

In this line `printf("%d \n", a + b);`

you are trying to addition an integer and a float, and the you print the result using the `%d` specifier. This shows the wrong result as an output.

In this line `printf("%d \n", a * b);` you are multiplying an integer and a float and printing the result using the `%d` specifier. It's also showing the wrong output as a result. To print the output correctly here you should use `%f`.